# Reboot and Select proper Boot device despite correct boot order

Tags: linux, windows-10, iso-image, bootable-media

I am trying to reinstall Windows 10 on an Asus R503C. I have created a bootable usb drive on my linux machine by mounting the .iso on the usb with `sudo mount -o loop ~/win10.iso ~/myUsb`. Now, inserting this usb into both of the Asus' ports, everytime it tries to boot up it gives me

> Reboot and Select proper Boot device or Insert Boot Media in selected Boot device and press a key

I have checked the boot order and put the usb (which is recognized in the bios) as the first boot option, yet it will not boot.

- Secure boot is off
- CSM is on
- changing the legacy usb support option doesn't change anything
- the USB has a MBR partition table, a single primary partition with a FAT32 file system   and works just fine

[Bios Information](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d4Umv.jpg)

[I should note there are two boot option entries for the usb](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VFBlt.jpg)

The win10 installation that is already installed boots fine if the windows bootloader is enabled as a boot option, but that's not my goal. I want to do a clean reinstall from the bootable usb. I really don't see my mistake.

Comment: This command `sudo mount -o loop ~/win10.iso ~/myUsb` writes nothing to any USB device. `mount` does not copy anything. It makes the OS show you some directory hierarchy under some mountpoint; this does not affect whatever was there before the mount.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you can **mount** an iso file in Linux does not mean that the USB has a usable **boot loader** installed. There are numerous tutorials for making a Windows installation USB from Linux, such as [this from Foss](https://itsfoss.com/bootable-windows-usb-linux/).

That said, since you *have* a working Windows 10 OS, it's much easier and more reliable to make an installation USB using [Microsoft's Media Creation Tool](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10). Note that MS will *not* let you use that tool if you use a browser running in another OS.

Also note that **Secure Boot is strongly recommended** for Windows 10, and also for modern Linux distros! Do *not* shut it in BIOS/UEFI.

Comment: That explains it. Thanks for your help, quite a Linux newbie so please excuse my mistake, seems stupid now... Regarding the Windows 10 install: It *boots* fine but that doesn't mean it's working, it's quite a malware infested device that's why I want to continue with the clean install.

Comment: @Tzatzikiiii an alternative would be to use [woeUSB](https://github.com/WoeUSB) to create a bootable windows installer USB on a linux system

Comment: @Tzatzikiiii, re: malware, use caution. Some malware (though rarely) can persist even after formatting a disk. If you can, boot from USB, save data, *then remove all partitions*, and set up the disk structure for Windows. Check the saved data for malware, then install Windows (which may take a considerable time). Installing dual-booting Linux, particularly a user-friendly OS such as Ubuntu, might take a half-hour, tops. BTW, ask a friend to make the Windows USB, if feasible.